# No Results when Using Inner Join Alongside Case Statement

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, dimensionStructure and dimensionDetail. When I join just within the NOT EXISTS after the Case statement, everything works beautifully.

```
SELECT ds.structureName, ds.dimensionName, 'Error' = CASE
when NOT EXISTS (select 1 from dbo.DimensionStructure ds 
                inner join dbo.DimensionDetail dd on dd.dimensionName = ds.dimensionName
                where dd.element!= 'revenue')
    THEN 'You must have at least one dimension that is tied to the element Revenue.'
    ELSE 'Test'
END
from dbo.DimensionStructure ds
where ds.structureType = 'revenue'
```

However, if I try to add a column from the dimensionDetail outside of the Case statement, suddenly I get no results.

```
SELECT ds.structureName, ds.dimensionName, dd.element, 'Error' = CASE
when NOT EXISTS (select 1 from dbo.DimensionStructure ds 
                inner join dbo.DimensionDetail dd on dd.dimensionName = ds.dimensionName
                where dd.element!= 'revenue')
    THEN 'You must have at least one dimension that is tied to the element Revenue.'
    ELSE 'Test'
END
from dbo.DimensionStructure ds
inner join dbo.DimensionDetail dd on dd.dimensionName = ds.dimensionName
where ds.structureType = 'revenue'
```

I'm not fully understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: it's probably not helping that you have ambiguous table aliases (you call them `dd` and `ds` both inside the subquery and outside).  And you probably don't need all four of the references.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with the `case` expression and subquery. The inner join is probably eliminating the row you had.

Answer (score 1):

You can try modifying your query to be like

```
SELECT ds.structureName, 
ds.dimensionName, 
dd.element, 
CASE
when dd.element != 'revenue'
    THEN 'You must have at least one dimension that is tied to the element Revenue.'
    ELSE 'Test' END AS 'Error'
from dbo.DimensionStructure ds
inner join dbo.DimensionDetail dd on dd.dimensionName = ds.dimensionName
where ds.structureType = 'revenue';
```

Comment: Oh that seems to work much better! Problem is it should only pull up the error if NONE of the dimensionNames that share a structureType has dd.element != 'revenue.' So if you have 3 dimensionNames, with a structureType of 'abc', and 1 of them has an element of revenue, then the error shouldn't pop up.

I think I missed that in my original code as well, let me edit it back in.